# Should Magento controllers be declared FINAL?

Tags: php, magento

In true Magento confusion there are two sets of controller classes; Those in the `Controller` directory and those in the `controllers` directory. The former have names like `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` and the latter are `Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController`. The latter are normally descendants of the former.

Because the latter don't cleanly map their names to their location in [PEAR naming convention](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php) they don't get autoloaded by the normal autoloader, you cannot `include` them from your scripts since you cannot be certain which code pool they are in and it potentially breaks the compilation feature.

I feel because it's so hard to extend them they should be officially `final` and be done with it. Will this break anything I'm not thinking of? Is it bad practice somehow? Can anyone suggest better terms for describing the extendible classes and damn-hard-to-extend classes?

Comment: Could you go into detail on the compilation breaking?

Comment: I once had an extension break when compiled because it used a hard include. My solution was to inherit from the overridden controller's ancestor, I found I didn't need to call any parent methods because they were all self-contained actions. I think I have since gotten stuck in the mentality of INCLUDE=BAD and controllers-should-only-extend-Controllers. Now that I look more closely at the code I can't see what broke originally.

Comment: I've settled on my own best practice. I will write all the actions in what I am now calling the "master" Controller. And the controllers will be empty descendants ("slaves"). That way any of my work can be overridden in the most convenient way and I'm not preventing anyone from working with the slave controllers if they wish to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be awful.

If you went back in time **maybe** you could make a case for declaring those controllers final to avoid the problems you're talking about, but introducing a  change like that would  **significantly break** a large number of Magento installations out in the wild.  There's numerous cases where extending a base controllers for new store functionality (or even override/rewrite functionality) is the right move.  Making them final now means you not only break applications, you break them in a way that's impossible to recover from.

Even if you went back in time, I'm not sure your frustrations (although understandable) hold up as reasons

#### No Autoloading

This sounds like more of a case for fixing and/or adding an additional autoloader

#### Cannot include them from your scripts since you cannot be certain which code pool they are in

I'm not sure I follow the concern here.  Including a base controller is as simple as

```
require_once('Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php');
```

No, you're not certain which code pool they're in ... and that's fine. The point of code pools is they have fallback PHP include paths, allows users to use their own version of a particular class if need be without wrecking the core.

#### Potentially breaks the compilation feature

I'm not familiar with the problem being described here, but again, it sounds like more of a case to extend/fix the compiler's functionality

Making controller classes as `final` to fix these problem would be like using a bazooka to handle a problem with house mice. The whole reason we have controller classes is so other URLs on our application can inherit functionality.  Even if you don't believe in that for projects where you're the architect, **taking that away** after granting it is, at best, a bad move.

Comment: +1 for improving the autoloader to work with the controllers.

Comment: Ditto on improving the autoloader, the naming convention for controllers is poor and if it wasn't I wouldn't have opened this question.

Answer (score 4):

people should use magento methods for getting the path for controller class and then it would't break the compiler as the methods would return the correct path.

```
require_once  Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout').DS.'OnepageController.php';
```

Comment: nice, hadn't seen that one before

Comment: there are usually two things that mess up compiler: hardcoded includes and licence files/schemes that are used and look for licence files or something else inside module directory

Comment: Ha! And you didn't mention Aitoc once.